# Swift 3, draw circle with special lineCap

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

Currently I'm using CAShapeLayer and UIBezierPath to draw a line for avatar. It's Ok for the normal one with **lineCap = kCALineCapRound**. BUT I've been STRUGGLING to draw line with **START** and **END** **lineCap** like image below:

[image]

Comment: add the corresponding code to the question, so we can help you to find a solution.

Comment: Hi Mina, thank for your answer. Stay focus on the picture with the blue line. You can see the starting stroke has crescent or sunken ( I don't know how to describe it, I'm from Vietnam). I need lineCap like this to stroke for starting point and round for end point. Here is my code:

let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
....
rectShape.lineCap = kCALineCapRound

Comment: did you make this? i am looking for a solution for this...

Answer (score 0):

You can't draw this circle with a shape layer, because a shape layer supports only one single stroke color. You should write your own layer class where you should draw three separate circle segments with `kCALineCapRound`:

1. A full yellow circle.
2. Draw the blue segment over the yellow circle. It is visible and you can see the rounded ends.
3. Draw a segment of the yellow circle, say 5 degrees of the top. Then you can also see the rounded end of the yellow line.

You should use `CGPath` and `CGContext` instead of `UIBezierPath`.

Comment: Thank macmoonshine, it's worth trying a little bit.